# Restkit low memory warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, restkit

I am using restkit since last few months for a project and I have really been in love with the magic it does to handle the complex operations like fetching json and saving into local persistent store. Although it has been quite helpful for me, I have been experiencing unoccasional crashes, the reason being low memory warning. Besides all the complex operation it is doing, I feel it uses a huge memory. Even if I disable the cache policy and inmemorycache usage, it is consuming a lot of memory. Is there anybody who has experienced the similar problem with restkit. I am sure some of you have come across this problem when using a big library for iPhone. Is there a way to delete or minimize the memory usage for mapping and other stuffs it does.

Any kind if solution would be much appreciated. I am eagerly waiting for any kind of helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you handling very large objects like NSData or something similar? Use ARC and @autorelease when necessary?

Maybe you're implicitly retaining lots of pointer references and memory isn't enough to handle. If you post a piece of code we could help you more.

Comment: I use NSData to download the images most of the time and the object is just a strong property which I need to reference from time to time.